As a British citizen, I get stopped for 40 minutes wait due to wrong record of refusal to entry
I came to the UK under a Tier 2 visa about 10 years ago. After the 5th year, I obtained my Indefinite Leave to Remain (ILR) and a year later, I became a citizen. Since I started using my UK passport, I have randomly experienced issues at the border as the border force officers see some sort of refusal to entry record with my name, date of birth, and birthplace matching. Given that I have a unique Turkish first and last name, it is highly unlikely that someone else has the same details.
Due to this issue, most of the time I am unable to use the e-gates. When the officers stop me, they take me to the waiting area and conduct checks for approximately 30-40 minutes to ensure everything is in order. Every time this happens, they come back and tell me I am good to go, but they do not know why they saw what they saw on the screen.
I have tried to reach out to Border Force via their complaints line, but they refuse to acknowledge that this issue is due to a wrong record. They respond by saying "Our officers have the right to do any checks they need to do their job," which I understand and expect from a border officer. However, the fact that they are doing this due to a wrong record is a waste of time for everyone.
I also reached out to my MP and received a response from the MP's Correspondence email. After asking for some information, they told me they cannot understand the exact nature of my email, even though the email clearly asks: "Is there any record of refusal to entry with my Turkish passport, and if so, what can we do to fix it?"
This issue causes great disruption to my travels, especially when traveling with my family. Leaving my wife and son to handle all the luggage while I am being checked is not ideal. There is also a risk of missing my connecting flight due to these random delays.
At this point, I am running out of options, and suing the Home Office seems to be the only way to correct this issue. It is frustrating to be stopped for an extended period, have my passport taken, and then be told I am okay to go.
I would appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I would suggest that you refrain from trying to diagnose the problem.  You may overestimate the uniqueness of your name, for example, or underestimate the fuzziness of Home Office similarity matching.  If the refusal of entry record was in fact for someone else, then seeking "records of refusal for [your] Turkish passport" isn't going to lead to a solution.  There may be no such records.  It may be, in fact, that these incidents are not "due to a wrong record"; there could be wrong logic or maybe even right logic.  Your goal is not to get them to acknowledge the cause of their past behavior but to get them to stop behaving that way in the future.
Instead, focus on the effect on you: the disruption impinges on your right to enter your country of citizenship and as you say is disruptive of your travels.  Also focus on the effect this has on Home Office officers and, by extension, the taxpayers of the United Kingdom: as you say, this is a waste of time for everyone.
I would try the MP's office once more with this approach.  Not "tell me what's going wrong" but "help me getting this to stop."  One solution would be to have your identity or at least your passport noted as not being associated with whatever incident is leading them to investigate you.  Or, if it is in fact some incident in your pre-naturalization past, to note that you are indeed legitimately naturalized as a British citizen.  I'm not aware of the UK having a system similar to the "redress number" of the United States, but presumably if they have a database record that repeatedly flags you for greater scrutiny, that record can be modified, amended, or linked to another record that should eliminate or at least reduce this additional scrutiny.
You might also try a newspaper.  I can't find it now but I have a vague recollection of reading a column covering someone's difficulty with some government department or other.  If a columnist will publicize your plight then you might see some relief.  Everything I could find just now was oriented to consumer problems, however, so it didn't seem likely that they'd take you on.
I assume you're aware of the Border Force's Complaints procedure page.  If you haven't done so already, follow the link there for submitting a subject access request.  You may find a useful clue.
Also, if you haven't already, pursue your complaint as far as the Independent Examiner of Complaints (link taken from the bottom of the main complaints page).  Even if they can't disclose to you exactly what the reason is for your troubles, they may be able to determine that it is indeed spurious and help to resolve it.

Thanks! I think I will reframe my complaint as you described. As it's they are too quick to see it as "Oh, our officer did their job and someone waited extra and get annoyed" regardless of the detail I share in my complaint.

@GO Do you have a log of how often and when you received extra checks? Being able to provide a detailed log showing 20+ times you were delayed might make more impact than just describing "I am being stopped a lot".

It is funny: You say "focus on the effect on you", and "there may be no such records"; only to go on and suggest "that record can be modified, amended, or linked to another record"! While I agree that the administration may be miffed when outsiders second-guess and criticize their procedures, this in the end is what is necessary. Sure, sugar-coat your approach and avoid wrong terminology so that your request is not right away rejected; but correct a record is clearly what they must do.

@GO The Guardian has a column where readers send in problems like the one you describe and a reporter tries to get to the bottom of it, that might be what phoog is remembering.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: The point is to phrase the request in a way that avoids any assumptions about internal procedures, because any mistakes in those assumptions give the administration a reason/excuse to reject or delay the complaint.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica "no such records" refers to records of past refusal of entry with the Turkish passport.  "Record can be modified" refers to whatever record is causing the extra scrutiny (which could be a record of past entry refusal with that passport, but is much more likely to be something else, since it seems that there wasn't in fact a refusal with that passport).

I suppose OP is showing them a British passport and at the border they should know there are no complaints against that British passport.

@terdon Newspapers are innundated with people writing in asking for help with this and that. The OP might just as well go buy a lottery ticket.

"I would suggest that you refrain from trying to diagnose the problem." This is really good advice to consider in so many interpersonal contexts.

@stackoverblown the likelihood of success may be small, but the cost of trying is also small.  For someone who is concerned enough about this to post on this site, it's probably worthwhile to try.

Hah, just after I post this, I got response to my latest enquiry to border force complaints (Another complaint I did after the one which didn't solve my issue) and it assured me I shouldn't experience further delays when I travel in the future. Hopefully this means I can start using e-gates. Let's see.
I think I will download this response from them to my phone, just in case.

I initiated conversation from multiple channels:

Via my MP, who raised my enquiry to home office and I got an email from MPE Correspondence team in Home office. However my replies to this office got handled by Digital Correspondence Allocation Team of UKVI in a really bad way. In each e-mail they sent, they asked me random piece of information which I already provided and they told me eventually they can't understand what my email asks and shut down the case.

Second channel I used and the one I referred to at the top is borderforcecomplaintsandcompliments@homeoffice.gov.uk email channel. It auto replied to me first, than 10 days later the actual response came. But this is not the first time for me, when I first experienced this issue I used this channel again and when I compare the letters they basically say the same things almost word by word. Given they assured me before, but I had the issue again I'm not 100% sure the issue is sorted.



Happy that you (perhaps?) have your problem solved.  If you feel that phoog's answer (or any subsequent answer that may be posted, if you do not find their answer sufficient for whatever reason) is a good answer to your question, please mark it as accepted.  Happy travels!

Right now, this looks more like a comment (or an edit) than an answer; but it can be turned into a useful answer for others if you include/explain what did you do differently this time to get your issue solved: where did you file the Border Force complaint, how did you frame the issue, how did you word the complaint for they to take you seriously this time. IOW, adding something along the lines of "so the solution was to write a complaint to Border Force through this link, and to explain facts A and B, not mentioning C or D, and requesting actions X and Z" would make this more useful.

Thanks for posting your experience as a self answer, please update it when you get more information.

Yes, I can try to provide a bit more detail. Tbh, somewhere along the way I lost track of whom I'm talking with as I initiated conversation from multiple channels.

Via my MP, who raised my enquiry to home office and I got an email from MPE Correspondence team in Home office. However my replies to this office got handled by Digital Correspondence Allocation Team of UKVI in a really bad way. In each e-mail they sent, they asked me random piece of information which I already provided and they told me eventually they can't understand what my email asks and shat down the case



Second channel I used and the one I refer in this parent message is  borderforcecomplaintsandcompliments@homeoffice.gov.uk email channel. It auto replied to me first, than 10 days later the actual response came. But this is not the first time for me, when I first experienced this issue I used this channel again and when I compare the letters they basically say the same things almost word by word. Given they assured me before, but I had the issue again I'm not 100% sure the issue is sorted.

